# glDeleteTextures not deleting texture

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks

I'm  trying to write a class to do fragment shader chaining by using a Frame Buffer Object to Render To Texture with a frament shader, then render that texture to another texture with a fragment shader, etc. etc.

I am trying to deal with a memory leak right now, where when I resize my window and delete/reallocate the textures I am using, the textures are not being deleted properly.

Here is a code snippet:

```
//Allocate first texture
glGenTextures( 1, &texIds[0] );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0] );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, screenX, screenY, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );

//Allocate second texture
glGenTextures( 1, &texIds[1] );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[1] );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, screenX, screenY, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );

//Try to free first texture -- ALWAYS FAILS
glDeleteTextures( 1, &texIds[0] );
//Try to free second texture
glDeleteTextures( 1, &texIds[1] );
```

When I run this with gDEBugger, it tells me "Warning: The debugged program delete a texture that does not exist. Texture name: 1" when I try to delete texIds[0]. (The reason I have them in an array right now is because I used to creating and free'ing them at the same time, however when you free 2 textures at once, it will fail silently on one and continue with the other).

If I don't create texIds[1], I can free texIds[0], but as soon as I create a second texture, I can no longer free the first texture I create.  Any ideas?

Comment: that snippet works for me when i declare texIds as `GLuint texIds[2];` immediately before. maybe the issue is elsewhere?

Comment: @6NSString Strange.  glGetError() returns 0, but gDEBugger tells me (and shows me, if I look in the texture viewer) that there are extraneous textures being created.  I am running OSX 10.6, if that helps at all.  I will also try creating a program that has _only_ this code in it.

Comment: Quite unrelated comment: To resize a texture you don't need to delete and regenerate the whole texture object, just call `glTexImage2D` with the new size.

Comment: Tell us declaration of texIds[]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the error is in texIds array. Is it array of GLUint?

You could erroneously declare it as array of word, thus when generating texture for [1] element, uint pointer taken from element [0] is broken.